# Eventemitter circular dependency improvements (Closed)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using event emitter and using a listener to each event, nothing weird or fancy pancy.

**emitter.js**

```
const listener = require ('./listener.js')

class Emitter extends EventEmitter {}
const emitter = new Emitter()

emitter.on(EVENTS.ACCEPTED, listener.doMoreStuff)

module.exports = { emitter }
```

**listener.js**

```
const service = require('./service.js')

async function doMoreStuff(bar) {
    await service.validate()
    return makeRequest()
};

module.exports = {
    doMoreStuff
}
```

Now my question is more related to solving the problem here with circular dependency.

My design decision might be bad, and would love some help improving it. Or if this is the wrong way to go.
My listener want to reuse som logic that is in service but this causes problems with circular dependency,

**service.js**

```
const emitter = require('./emitter.js)

async function doSomething(foo) {
    doSomeIntensiveStuff()
    emitter.emit(EVENTS.ACCEPTED, foo)
}

async function validate(foo)    {
    return true;
}

module.exports = {
    doSomething,
    validate
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolved it by splitting up my services even further.